# How to save url images in app based folder?

Tags: android, bitmap, directory

i am downloading the image from database and saving in download but want to save it in my own app named folder.

```
fabDownload = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabDownload);
        fabDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //check permission
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ViewWallpaper.this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Common.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog dialog = new SpotsDialog(ViewWallpaper.this);
                    dialog.show();
                    dialog.setMessage("Please wait......");

                    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                            .load(Common.select_background.getImageLink())
                            .into(new SaveImageHelper(getBaseContext(),
                                    dialog,
                                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                                    fileName,
                                    "CreativeGraphy Live Wallpaper Image"));
                }

            }
        });
```

to save i used image helper bitmap so i wanna know how can i add folder to save this images

**SaveImageHelper**

package com.blipclap.creativegraphy.Helper;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

/**
 * Created by Vinit on 3/26/2018.
 */

public class SaveImageHelper implements Target {

    private Context context;
    private WeakReference<AlertDialog> alertDialogWeakReference;
    private WeakReference<ContentResolver> contentResolverWeakReference;
    private String name, desc;

    public SaveImageHelper(Context context, AlertDialog alertDialog, ContentResolver contentResolver, String name, String desc) {
        this.context = context;
        this.alertDialogWeakReference = new WeakReference<AlertDialog>(alertDialog);
        this.contentResolverWeakReference = new WeakReference<ContentResolver>(contentResolver);
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        ContentResolver r = contentResolverWeakReference.get();
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogWeakReference.get();
        if (r != null)
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(r, bitmap, name, desc);
        alertDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Download succeed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

folder should be named with app name over here how can i add folder to save images it that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call it after download in SaveImageHelper class:

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap,String fileName) { 
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        File downloadfolder= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/NewFolder");
        if (!downloadfolder.exists()) {
            downloadfolder.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(downloadfolder, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            fos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: should i call after this  line            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(r, bitmap, name, desc);

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator + "YOUR_APP_NAME");
   boolean success = true;
   if (!folder.exists()) {
      success = folder.mkdirs();
   }
   if (success) {
       try {
           bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "YOUR_APP_NAME" + File.separator + "file_name" + ".jpg")));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                } else {
                            // Do something else on failure
                        }
```

Please try the above code

Comment: where should i add this in helper class or home activity

Comment: In your activity..